# is the iBeacon uuid is same as the MACID

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I bought an iBeacon from Amazon for experimenting with iOS and Swift.

the package has the following information on it:

Name: sanwo100038

MAC: EC24B8310BE1

Major ID: 10004
Minor ID: 5178

So there is no mention of UUID in the Beacon I got. Is this means this is not iBeacon compatible?

My code is giving an exception at this line which I think is because is not a 128-bits value?

is there a way to find out the UUID of the beacon or basically this is useless since is not ibeacon compatible?

```
let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: "EC24B8310BE1")!
```

Comment: You just tested with [Light Blue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8) Application .this will give you all information about your Device. That may helpful

Comment: LightBlue on iOS cannot read the ProximityUUID.  The OS blocks access.

Comment: @davidgyoung search ble scanner in Andriod. Apple Provide More Security for end Users.  some times its iritating for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously that is not the ProximityUUID, which as you say must be 128 bits.  It is unfortunate that it is not on the label.

Your best option is to scan for the ProximityUUID using a scanning tool for Android, OSX, or Linux.  Unlike iOS, those platfroms do not block access to reading an unknown ProximityUUID.  For Android, you can use the free [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dbeacon%20locate%20play%20store&pcampaignid=APPU_1__vM5VvJCifGZAZmLs_AJ) app.  For OSX there is ScanBeacon.

Comment: Thanks all. Light Blue on ios didn't show me the proximityUUID of the beacon, however ScanBeacon on OSX showed me all the info I needed and my program was able to recognize t he beacon